How can I redirect to an action but not first of view, but another part of view
this is my action to add new address on a step form , step form have 4 part that have a main Id for form , I want in the second tab add to new address and if method was success return to my view, but return to second tab , not first of view
these are my methods:
   

        [HttpPost]
    public  async Task<IActionResult> AddNewAddress(CartAddressViewModel model, int clientId, int activeTab = 0)
    {
        var userId = User.GetCurrentUserId();

        var result = await _orderService.CreateNewContactInfoByClient(model, userId);

        switch (result)
        {

            case CreateCartAddressResult.NotFound:
                return RedirectToAction("NotFound", "Home");

            case CreateCartAddressResult.AddressIsExists:
                ModelState.AddModelError("Address", "This Address is registered Before");
                await GetStateAndDistricts();
                return RedirectToAction("CheckOut", "Home");



            case CreateCartAddressResult.Success:
                TempData[SuccessMessage] = "New Address Was Registered Successfully";
                await GetStateAndDistricts();
                ViewData["ActiveTab"] = 1;
                return RedirectToAction("CheckOut",  "Home", new { activeTab = 1 });
        }

        await GetStateAndDistricts();

        return RedirectToAction("CheckOut", "Home", new { activeTab = activeTab });

    }



and this is main methd to show cart:
   

       [HttpGet("/UserPanel/CheckOut")]
   public async Task<IActionResult> CheckOut(int? activeTab)
   {
     

       var text = await _siteService.GetSiteSettingForEdit();
       var tax = text.Tax;

       var userId = User.GetCurrentUserId();

       // Get From Session
       var cartItems = _orderService.GetFromSession();

       // Update ClientId In ShowCart after Login
       foreach (var item in cartItems)
       {
           if (item.ClientId == 0)
           {
               item.ClientId = userId;
           }
       }

       // Get user addresses
       var userAddresses = await _orderService.GetClientContactInfoById(userId);

       // we check it in repo and create a list:
       //    List<CartAddressViewModel> cartAddresses = new List<CartAddressViewModel>();
       //so we don't need to check if null, because in repo 100% create a list for it with object, but not null

       var cartDelivery = _orderService.GetDeliveryAndPaymentDetailsFromSession();
       // Create CartViewModel
       var cartViewModel = new CartViewModel
       {
           Items = cartItems,
           Tax = tax,
           CartAddresses = userAddresses,
           CartDeliveryDateViewModel = cartDelivery,
           

       };


       ViewData["ActiveTab"] = activeTab ?? 0;



       await GetStateAndDistricts();

       return View(cartViewModel);
   }



How can I return to second tab of view of show cart?
this is part of view of showcart:
   <section id=" ">
       <form action="#">
           @if (Model.CartAddresses.Any())
           {
               foreach (var cartAddress in Model.CartAddresses)
               {
                   <div class="row mb-3">
                       <div class="col-lg-12">
                           <div class="input-group mb-3">
                               <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                   <div class="input-group-text">
                                       <input type="radio" checked="checked"  >
                                   </div>
                               </di

and this is my scrip to move between tab:
(function ($) {
"use strict"

var form = $("#step-form-horizontal");
form.children('div').steps({
    headerTag: "h4",
    bodyTag: "section",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
    autoFocus: true,
    onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
        // Validate the form on each step change
        form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
        return form.valid();
    }
});

var form2 = $("#step-form-tab");
form2.children('div').steps({
    headerTag: "h4",
    bodyTag: "section",
    enableFinishButton: false,
    enablePagination: false,
    enableAllSteps: true,
    titleTemplate: "#title#"
});

var form3 = $('#step-form-vertical');
form3.children('div').steps({
    headerTag: "h4",
    bodyTag: "section",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
    stepsOrientation: "vertical"
});

})(jQuery);

UPDATE
Update script under the page(not main script):
            $(document).ready(function () {
            var activeTab = '@ViewData["ActiveTab"]';
            if (activeTab) {
                // Wait until steps plugin is fully loaded
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#step-form-horizontal").steps("setStep", activeTab);
                }, 100);
            }
        });


Do you want to return to the second tab of the ShowCart view after processing the AddNewAddress operation? You can control which tab is displayed by passing parameters. Here is a simple example I reproduced with the code you provided for your reference:
In the controller's action method, I set the default tab to 0 by using the  ViewData["ActiveTab"] = activeTab ?? 0, which means tab2 is not activated. Then when the AddNewAddress method succeeds, use ViewData to set the value of ActiveTab to 1, and then read it in the Razor view.
     [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ShowCart(int? activeTab)
        {
            var cartItems = new List<CartItemViewModel>
{
    new CartItemViewModel { ProductId = 1, ProductName = "Product A", Price = 10.00m, Quantity = 2 },
    new CartItemViewModel { ProductId = 2, ProductName = "Product B", Price = 15.50m, Quantity = 1 },
    new CartItemViewModel { ProductId = 3, ProductName = "Product C", Price = 5.75m, Quantity = 3 }
};

            var userAddresses = new List<CartAddressViewModel>
{
    new CartAddressViewModel { AddressId = 1, FullName = "John Doe", AddressLine1 = "123 Main St", City = "New York", State = "NY", PostalCode = "10001", Country = "USA" },
    new CartAddressViewModel { AddressId = 2, FullName = "Jane Smith", AddressLine1 = "456 Oak Ave", City = "Los Angeles", State = "CA", PostalCode = "90001", Country = "USA" }
};

            var tax = 7.50m; 
            
            var cartViewModel = new CartViewModel
            {
                Items = cartItems,
                Tax = tax,
                CartAddresses = userAddresses            };
            ViewData["ActiveTab"] = activeTab ?? 0; 

            return View(cartViewModel);
        }
    }


        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddNewAddress( int clientId)
        {
            ViewData["ActiveTab"] = 1;
            return RedirectToAction("ShowCart", "New", new { activeTab = 1 });
        }

In the view, use the startIndex: @Html.Raw(ViewData["ActiveTab"] ?? 0) method to dynamically initialize the tab plug-in according to the ActiveTab value passed by the backend, and set the startIndex to activeTab. To make it easier to see that tab 2 is active, I added a collapsible method for it.
@model CartViewModel

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css">

<div id="step-form-tab">
    <div>
        <h4>tab 1</h4>
        <section>
         
        </section>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h4>tab 2</h4>
        <section>
            <button id="toggle-tab-2" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">toggle tab 2</button>
            <div id="tab-2-content" class="mt-3">
            
                <form action="/New/AddNewAddress" method="post">
                    @if (Model.CartAddresses.Any())
                    {
                        foreach (var cartAddress in Model.CartAddresses)
                        {
                            <div class="row mb-3">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                                <input type="radio" name="address" value="@cartAddress.AddressId" checked="checked">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-control">
                                            <strong>@cartAddress.FullName</strong><br>
                                            @cartAddress.AddressLine1<br>
                                            @cartAddress.City, @cartAddress.State @cartAddress.PostalCode<br>
                                            @cartAddress.Country
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                    }
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">sb</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts {

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-steps/1.1.0/jquery.steps.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var form2 = $("#step-form-tab");
            form2.steps({
                headerTag: "h4",
                bodyTag: "section",
                enableFinishButton: false,
                enablePagination: false,
                enableAllSteps: true,
                titleTemplate: "#title#",
                startIndex: @Html.Raw(ViewData["ActiveTab"] ?? 0)
                });


        $('#toggle-tab-2').click(function () {
            $('#tab-2-content').toggle();
        });

        
        if (@Html.Raw(ViewData["ActiveTab"] ?? 0) === 1) {
            $('#tab-2-content').show();
        } else {
            $('#tab-2-content').hide();
        }
    });
    </script>
}

On the default page after the program starts, you can see that tab 2 is not activated:

After expanding, I click the submit button, and the value of activeTab is successfully passed after the AddNewAddress method succeeds:


Tab 2 is activated:

If this is not the ideal situation, can you provide more details and a description of the problem?
update
@model CartViewModel

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css">

<div id="step-form-tab">
    <h4>Step 1</h4>
    <section>
        
    </section>

    <h4>Step 2</h4>
    <section>
        <div id="tab-2-content" class="mt-3">
            <form id="address-form" method="post" action="/New/AddNewAddress">
                @if (Model.CartAddresses.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var cartAddress in Model.CartAddresses)
                    {
                        <div class="row mb-3">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <div class="input-group-text">
                                            <input type="radio" name="address" value="@cartAddress.AddressId" checked="checked">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-control">
                                        <strong>@cartAddress.FullName</strong><br>
                                        @cartAddress.AddressLine1<br>
                                        @cartAddress.City, @cartAddress.State @cartAddress.PostalCode<br>
                                        @cartAddress.Country
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                }
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">sub</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-steps/1.1.0/jquery.steps.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#step-form-tab").steps({
                headerTag: "h4",
                bodyTag: "section",
                transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
                autoFocus: true
            });
            $("#address-form").submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault(); 

                var form = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                    type: form.attr('method'),
                    url: '/New/AddNewAddress', 
                    data: form.serialize(),
                    success: function (response) {
                      
                        alert('success');
                       // $("#step-form-tab").steps("setStep", 1); 
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                    
                        alert('error');
                      //  $("#step-form-tab").steps("setStep", 1); 
                    }
                });
            });
        });
     </script>
}

setStep method implementation and related views:
@model CartViewModel

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css">

<div id="step-form-tab">
    <h4>Step 1</h4>
    <section>
        
    </section>

    <h4>Step 2</h4>
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_Step2Partial", Model)
    </div>


@section Scripts {
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-steps/1.1.0/jquery.steps.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $.fn.steps.setStep = function (step) {
            var self = $(this); 
            var currentIndex = self.steps('getCurrentIndex'); 

            var missingSteps = Math.abs(step - currentIndex);

            var direction = step > currentIndex ? 'next' : 'previous';

            for (var i = 0; i < missingSteps; i++) {
                self.steps(direction); 
            }
        };

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#step-form-tab").steps({
                headerTag: "h4",
                bodyTag: "section",
                transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
                autoFocus: true
                
            });
            
            var activeTab = @Html.Raw(Html.Raw(ViewData["ActiveTab"]));
            $("#step-form-tab").steps("setStep", activeTab);
        });
    </script>
}


but this button has Id and after click it open a partial view to add  new address for user. after success method, I want return to the step2 of form, and update the page with last address and new address that was added. but it goes to the first of show cart view and after click next , I see Updated address, but I want to start from begin of second step of step form

Is your step2 using a partial view? Or are all the steps in your showcart view? Can you describe the structure? You use stepform and now you want to return to step2 of form after adding the address successfully?

no all of step2 is not partial .stap2 is the part of main view ( of cart view ) when click to add new address, open a partial view ,user can add new adress, after successfull adding it should come to step2 , but it goes to showcart but first of view ( step1), I want to back to step 2 to continue other steps( not first of view)

no all of step2 is not partial .stap2 is the part of main view ( of cart view ) when click to add new address, open a partial view ,user can add new adress, after successfull adding it should come to step2 , but it goes to showcart but first of view ( step1), I want to back to step 2 to continue other steps( not first of view)

You can set and pass the current step number in the controller, then add a current step property in the view model to store the current step, and set the current step in the view by setting startIndex to this step when initializing jQuery Steps. Just like my previous method.
There is another way you can use event.preventDefault() to intercept the form submission and send an AJAX request. On success or error, use the $("#step-form-tab").steps("setStep", 1); method to set back to the second step. You can refer to the update section for code examples.

I change the script with ViewDate, it return correct tab in url:
https://localhost:44371/UserPanel/CheckOut?activeTab=1
But again show Tab 0( I mean first of form) Check my script in edit question

more over, form for adding new address is a partial view inside of main view

I have this error:
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at String.replace ()
at F (jquery.min.js:2:36225)
at B.get (jquery.min.js:2:36831)
at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js:2:84556)
at HTMLFormElement. (jquery.min.js:2:85338)
at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2:3777)
at e.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2:1903)
at e.fn.init.trigger (jquery.min.js:2:85310)
at e.fn. [as submit] (jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js:154:131)
at HTMLFormElement. (jquery-steps-init.js:48:21)

Regarding the partial view and the problem you mentioned, I added the implementation of the setStep method and updated the code . Since the RangeError may be due to repeated calls in the code, you need to check if there is an event triggering the repeated logic.
